# How To delete parents and child table row using SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I want to delete rows from parent and child tables.

For Example

I have a two tables:
 1) **group**
 2) **group_member**

**group** table have the following fields:

> *group_id*, *Group_name*, *user_id*

and **group_member** have the following fields:

> *id*, *group_id*, *user_id*

I would like to delete something like this,

Supposing **group** table have
 *user_id* 2 and all members of *user_id* is available on **group_member** table

Table 1 image

[image]

Table 2 image

[image]

if delete query fires - all records with *id* = 19 will be deleted from both
 tables

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use `ON CASCADE DELETE` for this scenario.

From [MYSQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table. Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported. Between two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.

**Note:** Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use DELETE CASCADE, just use below tables and test.

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for candidate_master
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `candidate_master`;
CREATE TABLE `candidate_master` (
  `candidate_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `callerid` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `key_skills` text,
  `visa` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pvm` enum('voicemail','ping') DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isDNC` enum('NO','YES') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO',
  UNIQUE KEY `number` (`phone_number`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `candidate_master_ibfk_1` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `candidate_master_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `cgListUpdateLog` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for cgListUpdateLog
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cgListUpdateLog`;
CREATE TABLE `cgListUpdateLog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fail` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdatedOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` enum('NEW','PROCESSING','PROCESSED','FAILED') DEFAULT NULL,
  `dialStatus` enum('YES','NO') DEFAULT 'NO',
  `notDialed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filestatus` enum('processed','pending') DEFAULT 'processed',
  `comment` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

For any further help let me know!!

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are fine, but here is some SQL specific to your question. As mentioned use the database to do the magic for you.

Add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to the `group_member` table with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` reference option as such:

```
ALTER TABLE `group_member`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_group_member_group` FOREIGN KEY ( `group_id` )
REFERENCES `group` ( `group_id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

That will ensure a delete on the group with a specific id will cascade down to the group_member table.